# Erro ao imprimir lista encadeada

Tags: c, lista, lista-encadeada

Olá, estou com um erro na função que imprime uma lista encadeada.

Acho que o erro está no for da função imprime, mas também posso estar salvando o endereço de `prox` de forma errada.

Segue o código:

```c
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: pmargreff
 *
 * Created on 1 de Dezembro de 2014, 20:17
 */

/*
 * cria um struct que contém um nodo do tipo inteiro
 * e um ponteiro para uma celula do tipo do próprio struct
 */
struct cel {
    int nodo;
    struct cel *prox;
};
typedef struct cel celula;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

celula *cria(void); //por que a função é um ponteiro ?
void insere(int x, celula *pont);
void imprime(celula *inicio);
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    celula *inicio;
    inicio = cria();

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        insere(i, inicio);
    }
    imprime(inicio);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/*
 * cria uma função que recebe uma célula apontando para o ínicio 
 * e que aloca espaço para um tipo célula e passa a ser apontada pela 
 * célula inicio
 */
celula *cria(void) {
    celula *primeira;
    primeira = malloc(sizeof (struct cel));
    primeira->prox = NULL;
    return primeira; //perguntar para o andŕe o que isso significa
}

/*
 * cria uma nova váriavel do tipo célula chamada de "nova"
 * aloca espaço para ela, insere o valor no campo do seu conteúdo
 * o ponteiro da célula (ou seja) prox, recebe o valor que o ponteiro 
 * da célula anterior a ela tinha, o ponteiro da primeira aponta para 
 * nova
 */
void insere(int x, celula *head) {
    celula *nova;
    nova = malloc(sizeof (struct cel));
    nova -> nodo = x;
    nova -> prox = head -> prox;
    head -> prox = head;
}

void imprime(celula *inicio){
    celula *pont;
    for (pont = inicio -> prox; pont != NULL; pont = pont->prox)
        printf ("   %d\n", pont->nodo);
}
```

Depois de mais algumas tentativas, tenho uma nova função usada para inserção.

```c
void *insere(int x, celula *head) {
    celula *nova;
    nova = malloc(sizeof (struct cel));
    nova -> nodo = x;
    nova -> prox = head -> prox;
    head -> prox = nova;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente isso:

```c
void imprime(celula *inicio){
    celula *pont;
    for (pont = inicio -> prox; pont != NULL; pont = pont->prox)
        printf ("   %d\n", pont->nodo);
}
```

O correto seria `pont = inicio;` e não `pont = inicio -> prox`. O motivo é que o `inicio` é o primeiro elemento. Caso contrário você começaria do segundo, e o programa crasharia se receber uma lista com 1 ou 0 elementos.

Há mais problemas também:

```c
void insere(int x, celula *head) {
    celula *nova;
    nova = malloc(sizeof (struct cel));
    nova -> nodo = x;
    nova -> prox = head -> prox;
    head -> prox = head;
}
```

A ideia era inserir no começo ou no final? Seja qual for está errado para ambos. A linha `head -> prox = head;` faz a célula apontar como próximo elemento a si mesma, causando uma lista com um laço. Além disso, há um `memory leak`, pois a partir da `head` não é possível chegar-se a `nova` que foi alocada, mas ficou perdida na memória inacessível.

Para inserir no começo:

```c
celula *insere_no_inicio(int x, celula *head) {
    celula *nova;
    nova = malloc(sizeof (struct cel));
    nova -> nodo = x;
    nova -> prox = head;
    return nova;
}
```

Para inserir no final:

```c
celula *insere_no_final(int x, celula *head) {
    celula *nova;
    nova = malloc(sizeof (struct cel));
    nova -> nodo = x;
    if (head == NULL) {
        nova -> prox = NULL;
        return nova;
    }
    celula *ultima = head;
    while (ultima->prox != NULL) {
        ultima = ultima->prox;
    }
    ultima -> prox = nova;
    return head;
}
```

A ideia de criar a lista é criar o primeiro elemento dela. É isso que é retornado pela função `cria`.

Eu particularmente modificaria a função `cria` para já preencher o elemento do nodo criado:

```c
celula *cria(int x) {
    celula *primeira;
    primeira = malloc(sizeof (struct cel));
    primeira->prox = NULL;
    primeira->nodo = x;
    return primeira;
}
```

Ou então, basta usar a função `insere_no_inicio` passando como segundo parâmetro `NULL`, neste caso a função `cria` pode ser ou eliminada totalmente, ou reduzida a isso:

```c
celula *cria(int x) {
    return insere_no_inicio(x, NULL);
}
```

**EDITADO:**

Por fim, para usar estas novas funções de criação:

```c
celula *inicio = NULL;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    inicio = insere_no_inicio(i, inicio);
}

// OU:

celula *inicio = NULL;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    inicio = insere_no_final(i, inicio);
}
```

E você não pode se esquecer de destruir a lista depois de terminar de trabalhar com ela:

```c
void destroi(celula *inicio) {
    celula *proximo = inicio;
    while (proximo != NULL) {
        celula *destruir = proximo;
        proximo = proximo -> prox;
        free(destruir);
    }
}
```

Você sugeriu esta nova função:

```c
void *insere(int x, celula *head) {
    celula *nova;
    nova = malloc(sizeof (struct cel));
    nova -> nodo = x;
    nova -> prox = head -> prox;
    head -> prox = nova;
}
```

A sua nova função está errada, pois se ela recebe uma lista [A, B, C], ela muda os ponteiros tornando-a [A, N, B, C], aonde N é a célula nova. Ou seja, ela sempre insere na segunda posição. Se receber uma lista vazia, ela vai crashar.

Talvez ela pareça funcionar porque a sua função `cria` iniciava a lista com um elemento sem valor, e apenas a partir do segundo elemento é que os valores vinham. Mas neste caso você estará sempre desperdiçando o primeiro elemento e sempre que você quiser usar a sua lista para qualquer coisa, deverá começar com o segundo.

Por fim, o retorno `void *`, que não é a mesma coisa que `void`, não tem sentido. Usar `void *` significa dizer que a função retorna um tipo não-determinado de ponteiro, mas na verdade ela não retorna nada.

Comment: Olá, troquei a função insere para uma como você deixou a sugestão, porém não retorno nada. Qual a diferença prática de implementar como fiz à fazer como você exemplificou tendo como retorno um ponteiro para uma nova célula ? Obrigado pela prestabilidade ...

Comment: A sua nova função está errada, pois se ela recebe uma lista [A, B, C], ela muda os ponteiros tornando-a [A, N, B, C], aonde N é a célula nova. Ou seja, ela sempre insere na segunda posição. Se receber uma lista vazia, ela vai crashar. Na função que te sugeri, para inserir no início, você vai ter que retornar o nodo criado, que é o novo início, a nova cabeça da lista. Caso contrário você não teria como achar o novo início da lista. É importante você colocar `inicio = insere_no_inicio(i, inicio);`. Vou atualizar o texto para deixar isso claro.

Comment: @pmargreff Editei a resposta. Veja o que acha.

Comment: Agora entendi meu erro,e por que a sua função funcionou, grato !